# nginx client_max_body_size not taking effect

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, odoo

We have a Docker setup of Odoo with Nginx. Recently we needed to increase our max file upload size to 25 megabytes. Previously, we set it to 12m on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and it worked properly. So I set it to 25m like this: `client_max_body_size 25m;` but it didn't work for some reason (testing with a 20 megabytes zip file that returns 413). I have no idea why it's not working. We also have a site config under `sites-available/odoo.conf` and it has two server contexts and one location context (root). When the first one in the HTTP context didn't work, I tried setting the value on those three contexts as well, but none of them are working, I am still getting 413. I don't know what else to try. I have already restarted the server several times. It did work previously when I set it to 12m, I am not sure what changed since or am I simply forgetting to set it on anywhere else? Any ideas?

This is the error I am getting, by the way:

```
Uncaught Promise > server responded with invalid JSON response (HTTP413): <html> <head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head> <body> <center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center> </body> </html>
```

Comment: hi there, can you also share specific error message

Comment: IIRC Odoo itself is limiting filesizes for upload. Search for `max_upload_size` in js code and you should find the limit for your version and the code you have to customize, if you want to change that.